# React Router with React 16.6 Suspense "Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`."

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, dynamic-import, react-16

I'm using the latest version (16.6) of React with `react-router` (4.3.1) and trying to use code splitting using `React.Suspense`.

Although my routing is working and the code did split into several bundles loaded dynamically, I'm getting a warning about not returning a function, but an object to `Route`. My code:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Loading from 'common/Loading';

const Prime = lazy(() => import('modules/Prime'));
const Demo = lazy(() => import('modules/Demo'));

const App = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading>Loading...</Loading>}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Prime} exact />
      <Route path="/demo" component={Demo} />
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

The console warning is as follows:
`` Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`. ``

A normal import would return a function, but the dynamic import with `lazy()` is returning an object.

Any fixes for this?

Comment: That's odd you could try something like  <Route path="/" component={() => <Prime/>} exact />

Comment: @kasho That completely breaks my app. Found this issue, seems to be a solution: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using `render` prop instead of `component`

```
<Route path="/" render={()=> <Prime />} exact />
<Route path="/demo" render={()=> <Demo />} />
```

Comment: Thanks! Solution: `<Route exact path="/" component={props => <Prime {...props} />} />`

Comment: ronnyrr's solution worked for me. Also, I updated to the latest version of React, and React router (react-dom 16.6.3 - react-router-dom 4.3.1)

Comment: This is not a good solution because it will cause constant unmounting and remounting of these components if your redux connection is above this in the hierarchy.

Comment: So the best way is:

```javascript
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Prime {...props} />} />
```

In this case, you also received `props` inside the component.

Comment: Using inline arrow function as an argument for `component` prop will cause a re-render on each route change, which may be problematic if you are nesting routes and relay on lifecycle methods in rendered subcomponents. I would go with the @tmvnty solution instead.

Answer (score 11):

This will be fixed in `react-router-dom` version 4.4+ as this [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420) suggests

You can wait for the final release or if you don't want to change your code today, 
you can install the beta version now by `yarn add react-router-dom@next`

Comment: I can confirm that `react-router-dom` v5.0.0 solves this problem. v4.4.x seems to have been beta releses only before the major v5.0.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer do not respond the original question, but as I have experienced a similar issue, maybe my solution will help another people.

My Error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to "link", expected function.
```

Alike the accepted answer, this could be fixed with:

```
<Link to={'/admin'} title={'Log In'} component={props => <Button {...props} />} />
```