# How to change page title on separate header component depending on route with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React and have my project structured in a way that I have layout components and then the main page components. I want to change the title of the page in the header component depending on which route the user came to.

Here is my App.jsx:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy, Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './layout/Header.jsx';
import Footer from './layout/Footer.jsx';

const  Home = lazy(() => import('./pages/Home.jsx'));
const  Weather = lazy(() => import('.pages/Weather.jsx'));
const  Encryption = lazy(() => import('./pages/Encryption.jsx'));
const  Video = lazy(() => import('./pages/Video.jsx'));

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <>
                <Header/>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/weather" component={Weather}/>
                    <Route path="/encryption" component={Encryption}/>
                    <Route path="/video" component={Video}/>
                </Switch>
                </Suspense>
                <Footer/>

            </>
        </Router>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

My Header.jsx component is like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const path = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{path}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zl3y72k0pp

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. I've got a bit of a problem with the code. Any idea why it keeps saying `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
    in Route (created by App)
    in App`?

Comment: Thanks for everything! In case anyone runs into a similar problem to the one in my comment; [this fixed it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53019873/1934402).

Answer (score 3):

thre HOC [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) will provide the props `match`, `location` and `history` to your component.

then your can use `location.pathname` to manage the rendering of your component